Get event_endpoint for All Timeout @requestId in Single Query
I'm using CloudWatch Insights to monitor AWS Lambda timeouts. I have the following queries:
Timeout Identification:
fields @timestamp, @requestId
| filter @message like /Task timed out after/ 

event_endpoint Fetch (Single Request):
fields @timestamp, event_endpoint
| filter @requestId = '55fa4e92-63fc-4fd0-93e2-60ae367a5231'
| filter ispresent(event_endpoint)

How can I efficiently retrieve the event_endpoint for all timeout @requestId values obtained from the first query, ideally within a single CloudWatch Insights query? Otherwise I have to query for all the requestIds individually.
